# implement dependent combo box using lwuit

Tags: combobox, lwuit

```
private void buildUI() throws Exception {
        try {
            Display.init(this);
    countryLabel = new Label(resources.getString("Label10"));
            countryLabel.setSelectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            countryLabel.setPressedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            countryLabel.setUnselectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
country =  new ComboBox(countryChoiceDesc);             
            country.setSelectedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxPressedStyle());
            country.setUnselectedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxNormalStyle());
            country.setPressedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxPressedStyle());          
            CountryListener countryListener = new CountryListener();
            country.addSelectionListener(countryListener);      
    townLabel = new Label(resources.getString("Label12"));
            townLabel.setSelectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            townLabel.setPressedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            townLabel.setUnselectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
//          townList = new List(townChoiceDesc);
//          townModel = townList.getModel();
//          
//          town = new ComboBox(townModel);
            town = new ComboBox(townChoiceDesc);
            town.setSelectedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxPressedStyle());
            town.setUnselectedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxNormalStyle());
            town.setPressedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxPressedStyle());
            townListener townListener = new townListener();
            town.addSelectionListener(townListener);

            districtLabel = new Label(resources.getString("Label13"));
            districtLabel.setSelectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            districtLabel.setPressedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            districtLabel.setUnselectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
//          districtList = new List(districtChoiceDesc);
//          districtModel = districtList.getModel();            
//          district = new ComboBox(districtModel);

            district = new ComboBox(districtChoiceDesc);
            district.setSelectedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxPressedStyle());
            district.setUnselectedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxNormalStyle());
            district.setPressedStyle(DefaultLayout.comboBoxPressedStyle());     

            cityLabel = new Label(resources.getString("Label11"));
            cityLabel.setSelectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            cityLabel.setPressedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
            cityLabel.setUnselectedStyle(DefaultLayout.labelStyle());
}catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("build ui"+e.getMessage());
            dialog = DefaultLayout.validation(AppConstants.exceptionMsg);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }   
class CountryListener implements SelectionListener {
        public void selectionChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
            try {
//              Dialog.show("Beno","country action", "Ok", null);
                countryValue = countryChoice[country.getSelectedIndex()];
                getCity(countryValue);
                System.out.println("cityChoiceDesc.length :"+cityChoiceDesc.length);
                if (cityChoiceDesc.length > 0) {
//                  System.out.println("city set");
                     cityList = new List(cityChoiceDesc);       

                     ListModel cityModel = cityList.getModel();
                     city.setModel(cityModel);

                }
                    else {
                    String citylist[] = {};
                    List list = new List(citylist);
                    ListModel citylistModel = list.getModel();
                    city.setModel(citylistModel);
                    String townlist[] = {};
                    List list1 = new List(townlist);
                    ListModel townlistModel = list1.getModel();
                    town.setModel(townlistModel);
                    String districtlist[] = {};
                    List list2 = new List(districtlist);
                    ListModel districtlistModel = list2.getModel();
                    district.setModel(districtlistModel);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    dialog = DefaultLayout.validation(AppConstants.exceptionMsg);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    class CityListener implements SelectionListener {
        public void selectionChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
            try {

                cityValue = cityChoice[city.getSelectedIndex()];
//              city.setSelectedIndex(city.getSelectedIndex());
                getTown(cityValue);
                if (townChoiceDesc.length > 0) {
                    List list = new List(townChoiceDesc);
                    ListModel listModel = list.getModel();
                    town.setModel(listModel);
                } else {
                    String townlist[] = {};
                    List list1 = new List(townlist);
                    ListModel townlistModel = list1.getModel();
                    town.setModel(townlistModel);
                    String districtlist[] = {};
                    List list2 = new List(districtlist);
                    ListModel districtlistModel = list2.getModel();
                    district.setModel(districtlistModel);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    dialog = DefaultLayout.validation(AppConstants.exceptionMsg);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
class townListener implements SelectionListener {
        public void selectionChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
            System.out.println("town list");
            townValue = townChoice[town.getSelectedIndex()];
            try {
                getDistrict(townValue);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (districtChoiceDesc.length > 0) {
                List list = new List(districtChoiceDesc);
                ListModel listModel = list.getModel();
                district.setModel(listModel);
            } else {
                String districtlist[] = {};
                List list2 = new List(districtlist);
                ListModel districtlistModel = list2.getModel();
                district.setModel(districtlistModel);
            }

        }
    }
```

while selecting country it calls the town listener but city listener has not called but the coresponding values are updated in the city. while selecting city combo it does not call town listener why anyone help me out. Even I select the value in city combo box it does not show selected item

Answer (score 1):

You should use action listener with combo boxes not selection listener. Instead of creating a new list just use setModel() on the existing list.